# Run PhoneGap FileTransfer in background thread?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Why would an official PhoneGap plugin run on the same thread while at the same time warning you that it shouldn't?

All of the resources I find for running plugins in another thread are at the Objective-C level. Is the only option to fork the actual (official) plugin?

Thanks

Comment: if never tried but whats with web workers ?

Comment: Hrrm, that could be a possibility but I think it would only work for pure js plugins. I think the native side of js/native bridge executes in the same thread either way unless the plugin allocates another one. Not sure though, hope to get some more info on this.