# Cordova/Phonegap: run FileTransfer plugin in background thread

Tags: android, ios, multithreading, cordova

I saw an old unsolved question: [Run PhoneGap FileTransfer in background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355810/run-phonegap-filetransfer-in-background-thread)

Is there any news regarding this topic?

I'm using Cordova 3.4.0 with FileTransfer plugin and when i download a file the UI starts to lag expecially on iOS devices where the loading gif  is freezed for all the time

Is there any alternative plugin for download files smoothly?

Comment: what about this: https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-fetch

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the release notes for file-transfer. The issue has been fixed in the latest build:

> 0.4.3 (Apr 17, 2014)
>
> ... CB-5175: [ios] CDVFileTransfer asynchronous download (Fixes #24)
>   ...

Unfortunately this build completely breaks the file-transfer download by not calling either the success or fail callbacks. See [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6720?focusedCommentId=14008776&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14008776](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6720?focusedCommentId=14008776&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-14008776) for instructions on installing the last build that worked.

I manually patched CDVFileTransfer.m to include the background thread code from the latest version. In the download method you need to replace

```
[delegate.connection start];
```

with

```
// Downloads can take time
// sending this to a new thread calling the download_async method
dispatch_async(
               dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL),
               ^(void) { [delegate.connection start];}
```

So far this has been working reliably for me, but obviously you're on your own until Cordova releases an official fix.

Comment: I think they only fixed iOS. My app blocks UI on android and made it un-usable :(

Comment: I have seen something like that on Android as well, but haven't had the time to test it.